# Hortonworks docker sandbox is not loading in the browser

Tags: docker, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform

I have installed HortonWorks Docker sandbox as peer instructions.

Which seems to be running, when I type:

```
sudo docker ps
```

It is shown that the sandbox is runing:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                        NAMES
23dbac10e27b        hortonworks/sandbox-hdp:3.0.1   "/usr/sbin/init"    20 minutes ago      Up 20 minutes       22/tcp, 4200/tcp, 8080/tcp   sandbox-hdp
```

But when I visit localhast:8080 on the browser I do not get any response.

I also read that I should try ifconfig to verify the ip address:

Not sure what I should be looking in here:

```
br-193585a7edfa: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.18.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:62ff:fe32:c2fc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:62:32:c2:fc  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5  bytes 256 (256.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24  bytes 3241 (3.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

EDIT:

I´m startung it with this command, no porst specified:

```
docker start sandbox-hdp
```

As shown in the instructions:

[image]

Also I get the same ports mapping that is shown in the documentation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For container docker create separate network. 
If you need mapping of port for container in this network to port in host system you should specify it with `-p`

you need

```
 docker start -p <port_at_host_system>:<port_in_container> <image>
```

so run

```
docker start -p 8080:8080 sandbox-hdp
```